# Чем чревато отсутствие обработки OperationCanceledException у Task?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl

Чем может быть чреват такой вот `Task` с необработанным исключением отмены действия, если далее я к нему нигде не обращаюсь?

```
public static void Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(cts.Token), cts.Token);
}

public static void SomeMethod(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        // Некая трудоемкая операция
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    }
}
```

UPDATE1:
После ответа `andreycha` я решил проверить, как работает ловля ошибок у Task. И я заметил, что исключение отмены не доходит до глобального обработчика и никак не вешает систему.
В кофиг файле прописал:

```
<runtime>
  <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

Код:

```
public static void Main()
{
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs eventArgs) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task error");
        eventArgs.SetObserved();
        (eventArgs.Exception).Handle(ex =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception type: " + ex.GetType());
            return true;
        });
    };

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(1000);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter");
        while (true)
        {
            cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }, cts.Token);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        throw new Exception("Some exception");
    });

    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    Console.WriteLine("Collecting");
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Пример вывода:

```
Task error
Exception type: System.Exception
```

Выходит, что если тебе никак не надо обработать отмену операции, то можно в обще ничего не делать и ничего не будет все таки?

Comment: Не надо отвечать на свой вопрос в самом вопросе. Для этого есть кнопка внизу страницы...

Comment: @PavelMayorov А это и не ответ, это продолжение вопроса. Мне ниже написали, что можно словить исключение отмены в UnobservedTaskException и то что она же может положить программу, если стоит флаг  ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions . Но этого не происходит.

Comment: Закомментируйте `eventArgs.SetObserved()` и увидите падение. Потом поставьте `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions = false` и увидите прежний результат -- выводится сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: @andreycha Падение будет из-за throw new Exception("Some exception"). Отмена до туда не доходит, обработчик не запускается из-за него.

Comment: Да, из-за него. Просто потому, что оно случается раньше, чем отмена.

Comment: @andreycha не из-за этого. Я сейчас оставил только потоки с отменами. Нет этого исключения там. Попробуй мой код запустить

Comment: Запускал. Выводит точно то, что вы и написали. Обработчик `UnobservedTaskException` срабатывает из-за `throw new Exception("Some exception")`. Но приложение не падает по причине того, что вы вызываете `eventArgs.SetObserved()`. В чем вопрос? Быть может вы его четко сформулируете отдельно?

Comment: @andreycha Если убрать throw new Exception("Some exception"), то я в обработчике должен увидеть исключения из-за отмены в других потоков? Потому, что я его не получаю.

Comment: Вы его не получаете, потому что в `Task.Factory.StartNew` вы тоже передаете токен, и таск отменяется (находится в состоянии `Canceled`). Если токен убрать оттуда, то таск будет падать (состояние `Faulted`), и вы увидите вывод из `UnobservedTaskException`.

Comment: @andreycha В общем я тебя изначально недопонял, вот и все :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если приложение работает под .NET Framework 4 (или под .NET Framework 4.5+ с включенной опцией [`ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj160346(v=vs.110).aspx)), то когда сборщик мусора доберется до этого таска, финализатор выбросит исключение и приложение упадет.

В .NET Framework 4.5+ поведение изменили и приложение продолжит работать (а само исключение по-прежнему можно отловить в обработчике [`UnobservedTaskException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx)). Необработанное исключение ничему не помешает.

---

Однако я бы рекомендовал всегда обзервить таски, иначе вы не узн**а**ете, завершился ли таск успешно или нет и завершился ли вообще. В 99% случаев unobserved task -- это ошибка. Отследить завершение можно разными способами (зависит от вашей текущей архитектуры по большей степени):

1) Если вы уже используете async/await, тогда ожидайте так:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(cts.Token), cts.Token);
try
{
    await task;
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    // задача была отменена
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // другая ошибка
}
```

2) Если ваш код полностью синхронный, то можно использовать либо продолжения, либо синхронное ожидание.

Вариант с продолжением. Помните о том, что продолжение выполняется в том же контексте, что и оригинальный таск (т.е. в потоке из пула потоков). А значит обращаться напрямую к компонентам UI, например, нельзя.

```
Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(cts.Token), cts.Token)
    .ContinueWith(SomeMethodHandler, TaskContinuationOption.OnlyOnFaulted);
...
private void SomeMethodHandler(Task task)
{
    if (task.Exception is OperationCanceledException)
    {
         // задача была отменена
    }
    else
    {
        // другая ошибка
    }
}
```

Вариант с синхронным ожиданием. Тут надо быть аккуратным с тем, в каком конкретно месте вы ожидаете. Поскольку внутри `SomeMethod` у вас бесконечный цикл, то на строке `task.Wait()` приложение будет висеть до тех пор, пока задача не будет отменена

```
var task = Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(cts.Token), cts.Token);
try
{
    task.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    // синхронное ожидание, в отличие от await, не "разворачивает" исключения
    // проверяем e.InnerExceptions на предмет наличия OperationCanceledException
}
```

---

P.S. Если же говорить о коде, который вы привели, то он завершит свое выполнение почти моментально, не успев произвести нужную работу. Потому что таск никто не ожидает.

Comment: Как связано то, что таск никто не ожидает с работой, производимой таском?

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy `Task.Run` возвращает управление, метод `Main` завершает работу, приложение закрывается.

Comment: Да, все это хорошо, но работа уже могла быть произведена.

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy если, как написано в комментарии, там действительно "некая трудоемкая операция", то очень велика вероятность, что она не успеет завершиться до конца.

Comment: То что сразу закроется я знаю. Код написал для описания общего вида логики.

Comment: А как лучше обработать исключения? Мне в голову приходит только ContinueWith с флагом FaultOnly

Comment: @Nodon можно так (аккуратнее только с контекстами исполнения -- continuation по умолчанию будет работать в потоке из пула потоков, а значит обновлять в нем UI, например, нельзя). Или используйте async/await.

Comment: @Nodon обновил ответ.

Comment: `task.Exception is OperationCanceledException` - а чем `task.IsCanceled` не угодило?

Comment: @PavelMayorov я везде написал общий код для обработки исключений. Если уж говорить об отмене, то везде можно было бы проверять `IsCanceled`, а продолжение вообще сделать для `OnlyOnCanceled` и все :).

Comment: У меня тут вопрос возник. Если я делаю вот так `task.ContinueWith(t => { }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled)`, то у меня будет считать. что я обработал исключение об отмене? Exception таска на этом этапе пустой.

Comment: Я добавил кое что в свой вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Если использовать библиотеку [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog) - то там у класса `Logger` есть метод `SwallowAsync`, который позволяет залогировать асинхронную ошибку если она вдруг возникла.

Впрочем, стандартная реализация тут в любом случае не подойдет, ведь отмена задачи - нормальный способ окончания работы, а не ошибочный. В данном случае, когда весь код свой, я бы предпочел не создавать себе проблем вместо того чтобы их героически решать:

```
public static void SomeMethod(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;

        // Некая трудоемкая операция
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, в конкретно в моем случае, это удобнее. Но лучше привыкнуть писать сразу везде правильно.

Comment: @Nodon а такой вариант тоже правильный. Все зависит от цели. Если вы не хотите узнавать о том, что задача был отменена, этот вариант прекрасно подходит. Если же вам нужно узнавать об отмене, тогда да, лучше остановиться на исключениях.